# colorbox popup works fine on apache, will not load image on nginx

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, nginx, colorbox

This little bit of code works like a champ on a Apache based server.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*30;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
}
});
         </script> 
     <style type="text/css">
     .bssubpop { display:none; }
     </style>

    <p><a class='bssubpop' href="#">Subscription box</a></p>
<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='subscribe' title='sub'>
    <a href="/newsletter-sign-up.html"><img src="https://www.stogieboys.com/images/bspop.jpg" width="600" height="600" /></a>       
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I move it to the 'live' server, which is nginx based instead of apache, I get a the loading.gif forever and it never loads the image.

I know I'm new to working with an nginx server, but I'm starting to pull what little is left of my hair out.

Any and all help would be great.

FYI, yes I know the var fifteenDays doesn't equal that, but will once it works.  I checked the image location by typing in browser and it is right where it should  be so it's not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm a dumbass.  The colorbox.js files were different on the nginx site than the apache site.  When I had the time to trace and diff the files I noticed that and fixed it right away.

The var FifteenDays is now set to 15 days too.